# Need to find the difference between two dates along with the timestamp but I need to exclude saturday and sunday in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need to find the difference in hours between two dates along with the timestamp but I need to exclude saturday and sunday. Can you please help on this.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: If it is PostgreSQL, why did you put `oracle11g` tag as well? I guess you should remove it.

Answer (score 3):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4d313f6c6aeee283e1a307ae99b20d79)

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) * 24                                     -- 3
FROM generate_series(start, end, interval '1 day') gs -- 1
WHERE EXTRACT('isodow' FROM gs) < 6                   -- 2
```

1. Generate all dates between your start and end date
2. Asking for the `isodow` (Monday = `1`, Sunday = `7`) and remove all records with `isodow` value `< 6`
3. `COUNT` the records delivers the number of remaining dates/records, multiply it by `24` to get the hours.

---

**Edit** (Question more specific in comments):

To calculate the interval with different start and end times you could do:

1. Calculate the days from start + 1 until end - 1 (simply (end - 1) - (start + 1))
2. If isodow of start < 6 (start is not weekend) then add the time from start to next date ((start + 1) - start)
3. If isodow of end < 6 (end is not weekend) then add the time from end

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e214bede0f82051da0549d2ea7ea6b1e)

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) * interval '1 day'           -- duration of days exclude start and end
        + CASE                            -- add start if not weekend
              WHEN EXTRACT('isodow' FROM start) < 6 
              THEN (start::date + 1) - start
          END
        + CASE                            -- add end if not weekend
              WHEN EXTRACT('isodow' FROM "end") < 6 
              THEN "end" - "end"::date
          END
FROM generate_series(
    start::date + 1 , 
    "end"::date - 1, 
    interval '1 day'
) gs
WHERE EXTRACT('isodow' FROM gs) < 6
GROUP BY start, "end"
```

Comment: Thank you! this will resolve half of my issue, but actually if the start time column starts in any other time then in that case also it will calculate the entire 24 hours. Actually I need exact hours+min+secs.

Comment: I need the difference in hh:mm:ss,  I tried below with the help of your query and  the result is not exactly matching and  also getting the results in HH format. Kindly Suggest..Thanks!!              SELECT 
    count(*) ,id                                 -- 3
FROM testing.test,generate_series(eventdate::Date,dintervalstart::Date,'1 hour'::interval) gs 
WHERE EXTRACT('isodow' FROM gs) < 6   
group by id

Comment: Thanks for you help..I'm getting the output in 0 years 0 mons 2 days 24 hours 54 mins 16.159679 secs this format but I need it in like 72.54 as mentioned above...

Comment: You mentioned, you'll need exact hours, min, and sec which is, what your output delivers ;) However, to convert an interval into hours you can use the function `extract(epoch from my_interval)` which gives you the interval in seconds. Afterwards convert it to hours: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6136d319b65a2cb919dfab0100b7f3f8

Comment: Thank you so much!! Its working now as required

Comment: @SravanReddy Please don't forget to UPVOTE (which honors the time and effort, the replier invested into your problem) and ACCEPT additionally to close the question.